# Как в PyTelegramBotAPI настроить клавиатуру

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать так, что бы возврат информации из меню был простым сообщением, а не реплаем?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    but2 = types.KeyboardButton ("Моё местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(but2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Чего желаете?" , reply_markup = keyboard)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

[image: Проблема на пике]

Как убрать вот это "Чего желаете?"

Answer (score 0):

Такое невозможно. Ты не можешь отправить кнопку без текста.